# Can a TM decide the binary PCP-Problem？

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, rice-theorem

I am having a little bit of a hard time distinguish between a TM which accepts a language, and a $TM$ that decides a language. To be more precise:

$L_1 = \{\langle M\rangle\; | \; M$ accepts the 10-PCP $\}$
and $L_2 = \{ \langle M\rangle \; | \; M$ decides the 10-PCP $\}$

I guess $L_1$ is undecdiable, since I could potentially apply Rice's Thoerem Moreover, we know that the Problem that $M$ accepts $w$ is undecidable anyway. However, I am uncertain about $L_2$. For me, it seems intuitive to think that we could build a TM which rejects, if the input is a $01$-PCP Problem. Thus, the TM can decide it. But that seems a little bit too easy and I guess I am on the wrong trail.

Answer (score 1):

[The binary PCP is decidable](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397589900807). Let $T^*$ be a Turing machine that decides the language $L_{PCP}$ of all yes-instances to binary PCP.

We can use this fact to show that both $L_1$ an $L_2$ using a reduction from the halting problem.

Suppose towards a contradiction that there is a Turing machine $T$ that decides $L_1$ (resp. $L_2$).
Given a Turing machine $M'$ we can define a new Turing machine $M$ that, on input $x$, simulates $M'$ on empty input and then (when/if $M'$ halts) simulates $T^*$ with input $x$. If/when $T^*$ accepts $M$ also accepts. If/when $T^*$ rejects $M$ also rejects.

Now, $M^*$ accepts (resp. decides) $L_{PCP}$ if and only if $M'$ halts on empty input.
In other words $M^*$ belongs to $L_1$ (resp. $L_2$) if and only if $M'$ halts on empty input.

We can then use $T$ with input $M^*$ to decide whether $M'$ halts. This is a contradiction and hence no Turing machine $T$ exists.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that $L_2$ is undecdiable with your argumentation, since otherwise it would decide the halting problem?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: One last thing, is Rice's theorem applicable to $L_1$ or $L_2$?

Comment: I think so. To both $L_1$ and $L_2$.